# How can I catch Puppeteer error Missing frame isMainFrame=false?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, puppeteer

To simulate an error I rarely get but cannot reproduce in Puppeteer ^17.1.3, I inserted a throw at the exact same place:

```
PS C:\Users\User\Documents\project> node testingScript.js
C:\Users\User\Documents\project\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Connection.js:124
        throw new Error("Missing frame isMainFrame=false, frameId=3427AF206D1A9A044F89F086F2CB9AB6")
              ^

Error: Missing frame isMainFrame=false, frameId=3427AF206D1A9A044F89F086F2CB9AB6
    at Connection.onMessage (C:\Users\User\Documents\project\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Connection.js:124:15)
    at WebSocket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Documents\project\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\node\NodeWebSocketTransport.js:45:32)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\User\Documents\project\node_modules\puppeteer\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:199:18)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\User\Documents\project\node_modules\puppeteer\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:1178:20)
    at Receiver.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at Receiver.dataMessage (C:\Users\User\Documents\project\node_modules\puppeteer\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:528:14)
    at Receiver.getData (C:\Users\User\Documents\project\node_modules\puppeteer\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:446:17)
    at Receiver.startLoop (C:\Users\User\Documents\project\node_modules\puppeteer\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:148:22)
    at Receiver._write (C:\Users\User\Documents\project\node_modules\puppeteer\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:83:10)
```

No matter what I try, I cannot seem to catch this error.
How can I do that?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  try{
    browser = await puppeteer.launch().catch((err) => {
      console.log ("Error1: ", err)
    });
  } catch(e){
    console.log("Error2: "+e)
  }
})().catch((err) => {
  console.log ("Error3: ", err)
});;
```

Comment: Too many catches. One is all you need. Is it `.launch` that's throwing or something else? I'm not sure how to reproduce this.

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/8933

Comment: @ggorlen This is just to illustrate what I tried. The error cannot be caught by any of those. Reproduce: In Puppeteer node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Connection.js:124 insert throw new Error("Missing frame isMainFrame=false, frameId=3427AF206D1A9A044F89F086F2CB9AB6")

Comment: That is the real error I am getting, see also the issue you linked. I need to detect it and react. The manual insert just serves so that I can reproduce it reliably and test if my catch is working, and in fact it does not. Rolling back to an earlier version can be done, yes, but why is it not possible to catch an error that occurs here? Edit: I added it there because that's the error I am getting in production environment, exact same stack trace.

Comment: I see, thanks. "why is it not possible to catch an error that occurs here?" because you can only catch errors Puppeteer throws to you. If Puppeteer catches the error and logs it, then there's nothing you can do other than listen to stderr programmatically and change control based on it (clearly a hack). It seems to me that this isn't the sort of error that Pupp expects you to change control on--it's effectively a fatal error, I'm guessing.

Comment: Hm, but in the puppeteer code it throws with throw new Error(message), I do not understand why this does reach my catch statements. Fatal, true, but other fatal errors can be caught and according to my naive thinking especially fatal errors should be catchable in order to react properly. stderr is indeed hacky but actually a good idea, I just need to listen to it during startup, then can ditch the listener. At least this way I can restart the procedure. Thank you!

Comment: I haven't looked at the code, but you'll have to trace every function call from the source of the throw all the way to your code to check for any catches. If Puppeteer throws deeply in a func, then catches it (say) 6 calls up and logs without a rethrow, then that explains why your code can't touch the error. If you feel it's poor design, if I'm right about my analysis here, then you could open an issue for Puppeteer to potentially allow you to catch this. You could also modify the Pupp source on your local version to rethrow this error, but I'm not necessarily recommending this.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I would adapt the local version, but I fear I am not savvy enough for this. In any case, thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from puppeteer 18 the assertion is no longer there according to the developers, an update fixes the issue.